# Pushing indexes into an array without overwriting the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following example, if the `myArray.length` increases and with it the index, the value in the indexesArray will always be overwritten when pushing the new index into it.

I am looking for the cleanest way to push all the indexes in the indexesArray without overwriting the indexesArray.

```
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   let index = i;
   let indexesArray = [];
   indexesArray.push(index);
   localStorage.setItem('indexes', indexesArray); 
}
```

Comment: Pull `let indexesArray = [];` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reinitializing the array each time through the loop. This seems to be a common beginner mistake (I've seen it in hundreds of questions), no matter how obvious it seems to me that it's wrong -- just follow the code and you should see that you're wiping away the previous contents.

Initialize it before the loop, and save it to `localStorage` after the loop. You also need to convert to JSON before saving.

```
let indexesArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   indexesArray.push(i);
}
localStorage.setItem('indexes', JSON.stringify(indexesArray));
```

There's no need for the `index` variable, it's the same as `i`, so just push `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply obtain all the indexes using `Array#keys` and use spread syntax to convert it to an array.

```js
let myArray = [9,1,6,-5,0];
let indexesArray = [...myArray.keys()];
console.log(indexesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get the `indexesArray` out of the loop. You should consider getting data from localStorage if it is available as you are storing it. So finally your code should look like,

```
let indexesArray=[];

if(localStorage.getItem('indexes'))
  indexesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('indexes'))   //To retrieve the data if it is available in localstorage

for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   indexesArray.push(i);
   localStorage.setItem('indexes', JSON.stringify(indexesArray)); 
}
```

Hope it helps!!.. Happy Coding!!